# laravel having problem with show method of laravel

Tags: php, laravel, methods

i have a property model and i want to get the property show method and do some operation on it so i am on the show method right now consider the link below :

```
http://localhost:8000/properties/1
```

now from this link i submit a form to the route below :

```
Route::post('/properties/startreserve','PropertyController@startreserve');
```

and this is the controller of my startreserve and here i want to get the property  that i had in last page which means property number 1 in this example exacly like show method :

```
public function startreserve(Request $request,Property $property){


.
.
.
return view('users.properties.reserve')

    ->with('property',$property);
}
```

now when i pass $property its empty but i want to do it as the show method !!!
ok now for example i want to pass the id 1 property and make the link look like this :

```
http://localhost:8000/properties/startreserve/1
```

and here is my view code :

```
    <form class="m-form m-form--fit m-form--label-align-right m-form--group-seperator-dashed"
              action="/properties/startreserve" method="post">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            @if ($errors->any())
                <div class="panel panel-flat bg-danger">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h5 class="panel-title"></h5>
                        <div class="heading-elements">
                            <ul class="icons-list">

                                <li><a data-action="close"></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <ul>
                            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                            @endforeach
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            @endif
            <div class="row">
            @foreach($pdate as $index => $pdates)

                <div  id="checkboxes" class="col-lg-2 text-center">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="d[{{$index}}]"value="{{verta($pdates->date)->format('Y/m/d')}}-{{$pdates->price}}" id="d{{$index}}"/>

                    <label class="whatever mt-3" for="d{{$index}}"> {{verta($pdates->date)->format('Y/m/d')}}
                        <hr>
                        {{$pdates->price}}</label>
                </div>
            @endforeach
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <input type="submit" value="send" class="btn btn-primary">
                    </div>
                </div>

            </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the id on the route itself, as the route you have is not accepting the id.

```
Route::post('/properties/startreserve/{property}','PropertyController@startreserve');
```

So using a post request, you should be passing the ID in your action, you are missing that here.

```
<form class="m-form m-form--fit m-form--label-align-right m-form--group-seperator-dashed"
      action="/properties/startreserve/{{$property->id}}" method="post">
```

Comment: when i change to this i get the error that method post is not available for this kind of route and when i change both to get i get 404 not found with the link below

Comment: http://localhost:8000/properties/startreserve?_token=3KJj2LLvd0s4OVyyWJBg4rrrEtXcma6R7OvJcZzJ&d%5B0%5D=1398%2F01%2F12-21000&d%5B1%5D=1398%2F01%2F13-14000

Comment: Can you edit your question and share how you use the route in your view?

Comment: You need the property before you get to the post route in order to use it in your route. See my edit. But you should have the property before you render this page.

Comment: thanks its done and working and you saved me a lot time

Comment: Great, please consider accepting the answer. I answered one other question of yours today, if it helped make sure you accept them.